# Make a class with several objects of multiple subclasses parcelable in Android

Tags: android, class, parsing, parcelable

I have a class containing 2 subclasses and have several instances of those subclasses.

```
ClassA{
private ClassB obj1;
private ClassB obj2;
private ClassC obj3;
private ClassC obj4;
private ClassC obj5;
private ClassC obj6;

private class ClassB{}
private class ClassC{}
}
```

Is it possible to make such a construct parcelable? How would I do that or what are the alternatives?

Thank you for any help you can offer!

Comment: just make them all serializable, parcelabl = serializable

Comment: @HenningLuther Hi, the problem lay in my understanding of how the parcelable is build. Using the Parelable Plugin worked fine and did exactly what you suggested. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add a Android Studio Plugin for creating parcelable class.

Goto

**File -> Settings -> Plugins** and search '*parcelable*' and click on **Browse** and install **Android Parcelable Code generator**.

now open your class which you want to make parcelable and then 
goto

**Code -> Generate** (ALT+Insert)

and select Parcelable, select the field you want to be parcelable and thats it, it will generate the required code.

Do this for all the sub classes.

Comment: Omg. For whatever reasson I was under the impression that I could use only one of each class type to write to a parcel. Read: I can add one int or several ints via an array.  Thank you very much for the help and especially for the plugin. That helps alot!